# How do you set a breakpoint on a virtual address in a remote process?

Tags: c, winapi, x86-64, breakpoints, remote-debugging

I would like to analyze a program and have a handler be called every time a certain address in memory is accessed. I don't want to have to use an external program to do this for me. I was wondering if there was a straightforward way to do this using only C, perhaps some inline x86-x64 assembly, and the win32 API?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't so complicated to use a simple Debugger:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43682/Writing-a-basic-Windows-debugger

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132742/Writing-Windows-Debugger-Part

So you might use a data breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use [SetThreadContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680632(v=vs.85).aspx) to set the [debug registers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_debug_register)

Comment: Setting the debug registers is necessary, but not sufficient; you also need to have a handler for the event.